# When were pointers added to C / C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am not sure if this is a valid question, but I need to know if pointers have always been a part of C/C++ or when they were added?

I have found an overview of C/C++ history which states that references were added 1985 in Cfront 1.0 and that pointers to members were added 1989 in Cfront 2.0. Still I need to know when "general" pointers were added respectively if they were part of C when it was introduced 1979?

Answer (score 2):

The version of the C Reference Manual that came with 6th Edition Unix (**May 1975**), in the second volume entitled ``Documents for Use With the Unix Time-sharing System'' already contained a description of pointers.

From the [*manual*](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf)

> Besides the four fundamental types there is a conceptually infinite
>   class of derived types constructed from the fundamental types in the
>   following ways:

```
arrays of objects of most types;
functions which return objects of a given type;
pointers to objects of a given type;
structures containing objects of various types.
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened in 1971, in the direct precursor of C, which at the time was called [NB](https://sites.harvard.edu/~lib113/reference/c/c_history.html) (for New B).

C evolved from B, which evolved from BCPL. Both B and C were the products of Kernighan and Ritchie.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan): "Kernighan affirmed that he had no part in the design of the C language ("it's entirely Dennis Ritchie's work")".

Comment: IMO, the best thing anyone can learn from this thread is that C used to be called "New B"! So we've always been so highly uninventive at naming things since the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers were already present in BCPL (where the operator `!` indirected through a value, i.e., treated it as a pointer).

BCPL -> B -> C -> "C with classes" -> C++...

Comment: Actually, in B there were no types, and therefore no pointers. Instead, the operation determined how its argument was interpreted. That's still how many CPU's work, so it's not entirely weird.

Comment: @MSalters: I stated that pointers were present *in BCPL*, by virtue of the `!` operator that indirects through a value, i.e. treating it as an address. Besides, B offered the same feature.

Comment: It goes back further, and depends on what you call a "pointer".    BCPL was a simplified ("basic") version of a language called CPL.   In CPL, there weren't variables as such, - it worked with values in a stack that were all of the same size, but could represent conceptual types such as an integer, a pointer, or a function (essentially a pointer to the first instruction).  The design of CPL was influenced by Algol, and early versions of Algol were influenced by early versions of Fortran - which passed all function arguments by reference (implemented as a set of pointers...)

Comment: @Peter: BCPL was the earliest of the chain that actually influenced things I did myself (AmigaOS had some BCPL artifacts), so I usually stop there so I don't get caught out in unknown territory (a.k.a. talking out of my backside). ;-)